# Confused about comparison of Pearson coefficients

Tags: correlation, pearson-r

I am slightly confused on a paper I am reading. They have a table of calculated Pearson coefficients as shown here:

$$
\begin{array}
 . & I & II & III\\
A + B & 0.8 & 0.65 & 0.90\\
A + C & 0.73 & 0.46 & 0.83\\
B + C & 0.61 & 0.76 & 0.68\\
\end{array}
$$

They claim that the weakest correlation recorded was between $B+C, \,\, I$ and $B+C, \,\, III$. $A,B,C$ are different imaging modalities.

Are they stating that these are the two closest values in one comparison (i.e $B+C$)?

I am confused because they are now correlating correlations!

I thought the the weakest correlations would be $B+C, \,\, I$ and $A+C, \,\, II$, as they have the smallest values, but perhaps I did not understand their statement.

The paper can be found here: http://online.medphys.org/resource/1/mphya6/v40/i4/p041707_s1?bypassSSO=1

Page 4, section III.B

Comment: Can you give a reference, or at least some kind of direct quote so we can see what they actually say?

Comment: I have added the URL to the paper. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm looking at the html version, so page numbers don't help. If you mean the figures in Table II, the correlations there don't match what you have typed in.

Comment: Yes, that is the table. They have made errors (one I believe 0.5 should be 0.65). I do not know how this paper got published, lots of errors.

Comment: The presence of errors in the values makes it hard to say much of anything because their comments may be based on numbers other than the ones either of us are looking at. Maybe they made yet another table between the original figures and the published table and their comments refer to that - if they are so careless, how could we tell what else may have happened? You'd need to ask the authors.

Comment: Thanks you for your comments. But would there statement be correct? Is it correct to say that if two correlations are close in values (within a given group) that they have a weak correlation? As in the table above, the smallest difference between two correlations is 0.61-0.69 as they state?

Comment: I see, that's what I thought. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Since our discussion went for some time I have turned my comments and responses into an answer of sorts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of errors in the values makes it hard to say much of anything because their comments may be based on numbers other than the ones either of us are looking at. Maybe they made yet another table between the original figures and the published table and their comments refer to that - if they are so careless, how could we tell what else may have happened? You'd need to ask the authors.

> would their statement be correct? Is it correct to say that if two correlations are close in value (within a given group) that they have a weak correlation? As in the table above, the smallest difference between two correlations is 0.61-0.69 as they state?

The comment about weak correlation would presumably be because the correlation values themselves aren't large; you can't pick two correlations that are similar in size and thereby claim that the correlations are themselves correlated.

There may be an argument that some of the correlations are in turn correlated, but an argument based on their values doesn't establish that.